# Unable to send messages via SMTP mailkit and Gmail API using Service Account

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, gmail, mailkit

I've been working for some time to try and get this system to work with the gmail api system and a service account (to avoid creating an empty user account), and I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

```cs
        public static async Task<ServiceResponse> SendMail(ContactUsModel ContactInfo)
        {
            ServiceResponse response = new ServiceResponse();

            try
            {
                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"cert.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
                var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("service account")
                {
                    // Note: other scopes can be found here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes
                    Scopes = new[] { "https://mail.google.com" },
                    User = "service account"
                }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                // Note: result will be true if the access token was received successfully
                bool result = await credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);

                // create an OAuth2 SASL context
                var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2("service account", credential.Token.AccessToken);

                MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage();
                msg.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(ContactInfo.Name, ContactInfo.EmailAddress));
                msg.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Me", "business email account"));
                msg.Subject = ContactInfo.Subject;
                msg.Body = new TextPart("plain")
                {
                    Text = $"From: {ContactInfo.Name}\nEmail: {ContactInfo.EmailAddress}\nDate:{ContactInfo.AppointmentDate.ToString()}\nMessage: {ContactInfo.Message}"
                };

                using(SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
                    client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                    client.Authenticate(oauth2);
                    client.Send(msg);
                    client.Disconnect(true);
                }

                response.Success = true;
                response.Message = "Message Sent";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                response.Success = false;
                response.Message = "An error occurred. Please call us.";
            }

            return response;
        }
```

I enabled the gmail api, and set the service account to cloud function invoker.

This is the error I'm currently getting, and I'm not sure why.

```
{"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}
```

Edit:
Update code and update error message.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong scope. The "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send" scope is for using an HTTP-based protocol library to send messages.

You need the "https://mail.google.com/" scope for use with IMAP, POP3, and/or SMTP protocols.

Comment: After changing the scope, I still receive the same error message.

Comment: The problem I was having was a mismatched email with the service account. I now updated the code above, with a new error message I'm not quite understanding. The other SO answer said it was their scope, but I'm using the same scope.

Comment: Did you solve it? I get the same error :(